# Updating a dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Current issue: Taking input to select a dictionary key, and add in a `quantity` key:value pair to that nested dictionary.

This is my attempt

```py
menu = {
    1: {"item": "Green Beret Omelette", "price": "$12.99"},
    2: {"item": "Get to the Chopped Salad", "price": "$14.99"},
    3: {"item": "Pump You Up Protein Shake", "price": "$9.99"},
    4: {"item": "I'll Be Baby Back Ribs", "price": "$22.99"},
    5: {"item": "Let Off Some Steamed Vegetables", "price": "$4.99"},
    6: {"item": "The Ice Cream Cometh", "price": "$15.99"}
}

selection = int(input("Please select your item:\n"))
if int(selection) < 1 or int(selection) > 6:
    print("Invalid selection. Please try again. \n")

count = int(input("Enter quantity: \n"))

# This is the line I'd like help with
menu[selection].update["quantity": count]
```

How do I structure the line `menu[selection].update["quantity": count]` so that menu would be updated to:

```py
menu = {
    1: {"item": "Green Beret Omelette", "price": "$12.99", "quantity": 2},  # Note the new k:v here
    2: {"item": "Get to the Chopped Salad", "price": "$14.99"},
    3: {"item": "Pump You Up Protein Shake", "price": "$9.99"},
    4: {"item": "I'll Be Baby Back Ribs", "price": "$22.99"},
    5: {"item": "Let Off Some Steamed Vegetables", "price": "$4.99"},
    6: {"item": "The Ice Cream Cometh", "price": "$15.99"}
}
```

Comment: `menu[selection]['quantity'] = count`?

Comment: YOu don't have the price key in the dictionary first item

Comment: Good catch on the price key, I accidentally deleted it when posting the expected value in the bottom, editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
# Use 'dict.update()` with inputting a dict with key and value as you like
menu[selection].update({"quantity": count})
```

Run with input:

```
Please select your item:
1
Enter quantity: 
2
```

Output:

```
# print(menu)
{1: {'item': 'Green Beret Omelette', 'quantity': 2, 'price': '$12.99'},
 2: {'item': 'Get to the Chopped Salad', 'price': '$14.99'},
 3: {'item': 'Pump You Up Protein Shake', 'price': '$9.99'},
 4: {'item': "I'll Be Baby Back Ribs", 'price': '$22.99'},
 5: {'item': 'Let Off Some Steamed Vegetables', 'price': '$4.99'},
 6: {'item': 'The Ice Cream Cometh', 'price': '$15.99'}}
```

Comment: This looks good, I realized I deleted the price entry on the original dict so I've updated my question. I'll edit your answer so it's still in line with the question once the edit queue isn't full

Answer (score 1):

OPH (Original problem haver) here. I asked Jamie for help, and he posted for me, so give him all the upvotes.

Here is an updated version/attempt.

```
menu = {
1: {"item": "Green Beret Omelette", "price": "$12.99"},
2: {"item": "Get to the Chopped Salad", "price": "$14.99"},
3: {"item": "Pump You Up Protein Shake", "price": "$9.99"},
4: {"item": "I'll Be Baby Back Ribs", "price": "$22.99"},
5: {"item": "Let Off Some Steamed Vegetables", "price": "$4.99"},
6: {"item": "The Ice Cream Cometh", "price": "$15.99"}
}

key = int(input("Please select your item:\n"))
    if int(key) < 1 or int(key) > 6:
        print("Invalid selection. Please try again. \n")
        isOrdering = True
        continue
    
    quan = int(input("Enter quantity: \n")), menu.update[key]({"quantity": quan})
    
    menu[key]["subTotal"] = menu[key]("quantity") * menu[key]("price")
```

The error I'm currently running into is "Exception has occurred: TypeError
'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable" for the line:

quan = int(input("Enter quantity: \n")), menu.update[key]({"quantity": quan})

Comment: Hey Tim, I'd post this as a new SO question